# How to add SQL database and crystal reports to deployment project(setup project) in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm working on a project (it's an institute management system) using visual basic and MS-SQL Server for my database(.sql) along with Crystal Reports.
I have created a deployment project in Visual Studio 2019, how can I add a SQL  database and Crystal Reports in the deployment project in Visual Studio 2019?

because after finishing the deployment project and getting the setup file it works fine in the PC that i used for creating the whole project as i already have MS-SQL server 2019 and Crystal Reports installed and  When I run it on a different PC, the database and the reports don't work.

Comment: Any specific dbms in mind? (The <sql> tag is for questions related to the SQL _language_.)

Comment: I'm using MS Sql server

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean by "creating a setup file"? There are numerous ways to create an installer so you need to specify. If you're using the Publish wizard then you're creating a ClickOnce installer, which is very different to creating a Setup project to use Windows Installer. Also, to say that your database "does not work" is wholly inadequate. You need to explain EXACTLY what you're doing and what actually happens. What database? Do you mean an MDF file deployed with your app or an attached database on an existing instance? Visit the Help Center to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: Could you provide more detailed description of your question with some pictures? It will help others analyze your problem.

Comment: is it clear now? i need help